# wso2 api manager shuts down after few days on its own

Tags: wso2-api-manager

WSO2 API Manager shuts down on its own after few days. Is there a configuration which I need to tweak, so that this doesn't happen in production?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided log, it clearly says that someone has triggered the shutdown hook mistakenly.

> INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Shutdown hook triggered....

WSO2 API Manager normally won't shutdown automatically.

Comment: Great..Thanks for the reply. To further debug how his happened, can you tell me what is this shutdown hook? is it a kill command? or some wso2 script?

Comment: Basically, how you start the wso2 server in background is using the './wso2server.sh start' command. You can find the wso2server.sh script in wso2am-2.0.0/bin location. To shutdown the server, command would be './wso2server.sh stop'. This stop command is to trigger gracefully shutdown which also means the server will serve ongoing requests at that time.  If you are having a service for running the wso2server, please check that configuration as well.

Comment: I use "$ nohup ./wso2server.sh &" to start. Do you think that is the issue?